Flutter GetX - Navigate to specific page after notification, but return to home page on back press
I have created a small app in Flutter, and I'm using GetX as my state manager for navigation. When I receive a notification, I want to navigate to a specific page, and it's working fine. However, when I press the back button after viewing the specific page, the app closes instead of navigating back to the home page.
This is the code I am using to handle the navigation when a notification is received:
void handleMessage(RemoteMessage? message) {
  if (message == null) return;

  final data = message.data;
  Get.to(() => ViewNewsScreen(url: data["news_url"]));
}

The problem is that after opening ViewNewsScreen from the notification, pressing the back button exits the app. I want it to return to the home page instead.
I am not using any named routes and would prefer to stick to the GetX navigation system. How can I fix this?
Any help would be appreciated!

you can try the named routing in GetX; it will work absolutely

something like this
GetPage(
name: '/',
page: () => const HomeView(),
),
GetPage(
name: '/second-screen',
page: () => const SecondScreenView(),
),

i have not learnt named routing, so that's why i was thinking on making it work somehow.

If you want to ensure that pressing the back button always returns to the home screen when you come from the notification, you can customize the back button behavior in ViewNewsScreen.
Wrap your ViewNewsScreen in a WillPopScope and define the back button behavior:
class ViewNewsScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        // Navigate back to the home screen when back button is pressed. 
        // Here You have to add condition for check it come from notification or not.
        Get.offAll(() => HomeScreen());
        return false; // Prevent the default back navigation
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Text("View News")),
        body: Center(child: Text("News Details")),
      ),
    );
  }
}

